# Error message about unexpected symbol while creating JSON with fromJSON

Tags: r, jsonlite

It's probably an easy thing, but I'm struggling a lot with creating a simple JSON file with a simple text input. Form teh error message it's clear that I'md oding sth. wrong with quotes, but I've no idea what.

```
library(jsonlite)

# Create an example
jsoncars <- toJSON(mtcars[1:2,], pretty=TRUE)
jsoncars
```

This gives:

```
[
  {
    "mpg": 21,
    "cyl": 6,
    "disp": 160,
    "hp": 110,
    "drat": 3.9,
    "wt": 2.62,
    "qsec": 16.46,
    "vs": 0,
    "am": 1,
    "gear": 4,
    "carb": 4,
    "_row": "Mazda RX4"
  },
  {
    "mpg": 21,
    "cyl": 6,
    "disp": 160,
    "hp": 110,
    "drat": 3.9,
    "wt": 2.875,
    "qsec": 17.02,
    "vs": 0,
    "am": 1,
    "gear": 4,
    "carb": 4,
    "_row": "Mazda RX4 Wag"
  }
]
```

Now, I'm copying this very same text into fromJSON:

```
fromJSON("[
  {
    "mpg": 21,
    "cyl": 6,
    "disp": 160,
    "hp": 110,
    "drat": 3.9,
    "wt": 2.62,
    "qsec": 16.46,
    "vs": 0,
    "am": 1,
    "gear": 4,
    "carb": 4,
    "_row": "Mazda RX4"
  },
  {
    "mpg": 21,
    "cyl": 6,
    "disp": 160,
    "hp": 110,
    "drat": 3.9,
    "wt": 2.875,
    "qsec": 17.02,
    "vs": 0,
    "am": 1,
    "gear": 4,
    "carb": 4,
    "_row": "Mazda RX4 Wag"
  }
]")
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"      {
        "mpg"
Execution halted
```

BTW, doing `fromJSON(jsoncars)` works, but it still doesn't solve my problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'` to differentiate from `"` in `JSON` text :

```
jsonlite::fromJSON('[
  {
    "mpg": 21,
    "cyl": 6,
    "disp": 160,
    "hp": 110,
    "drat": 3.9,
    "wt": 2.62,
    "qsec": 16.46,
    "vs": 0,
    "am": 1,
    "gear": 4,
    "carb": 4,
    "_row": "Mazda RX4"
  },
  {
    "mpg": 21,
    "cyl": 6,
    "disp": 160,
    "hp": 110,
    "drat": 3.9,
    "wt": 2.875,
    "qsec": 17.02,
    "vs": 0,
    "am": 1,
    "gear": 4,
    "carb": 4,
    "_row": "Mazda RX4 Wag"
  }
]')

              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Another option is the new R>=4.0 [raw character string](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html) syntax `r"(...)"`:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(r"([
  {
    "mpg": 21,
    "cyl": 6,
    "disp": 160,
    "hp": 110,
    "drat": 3.9,
    "wt": 2.62,
    "qsec": 16.46,
    "vs": 0,
    "am": 1,
    "gear": 4,
    "carb": 4,
    "_row": "Mazda RX4"
  },
  {
    "mpg": 21,
    "cyl": 6,
    "disp": 160,
    "hp": 110,
    "drat": 3.9,
    "wt": 2.875,
    "qsec": 17.02,
    "vs": 0,
    "am": 1,
    "gear": 4,
    "carb": 4,
    "_row": "Mazda RX4 Wag"
  }
])")
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm sure I used single quotes in one of my attempts without success. But now it does. Probably something else wasn't correct when I did the single quote attempt. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Waldi just out of interest: if you switch " and ' in the first answer you've given (i.e. the string is wrapped with double quotes and the keys are wrapped with single quotes) it doesn't work. Any reason why the opening and closing tags have to be single quoted?

Comment: @Johnny, I think this is [json string specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)